# How to Pass Values to Window in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to pass a stored preference value to a text box in a settings window that can be opened from a user login window. I am planning to do this by setting the value in the controller prior to open. As you can see, I am also trying to make the settings window a child of the login window. However, I am getting `javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane cannot be cast to javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader` for reasons that I don't understand and am completely at a loss as to what to do.

My code for opening the settings window on the press of a button is as follows:

```
@FXML
void OpenSettingsWindow(ActionEvent event) {

    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader.load(SettingsWindowController.class
                .getResource("Settings.fxml"));
        AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(SettingsWindowController.class
                .getResource("Settings.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(page);
        root = new Stage();

        root.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        root.initOwner(Main.primaryStage);
        root.setScene(scene);
        SettingsWindowController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
        String databaseAddressValue = "databaseAddressValue";
        controller.setDatabaseAddressValue(Preferences
            .systemRoot()
            .node("preferences.SystemPreferences")
            .get(SystemPreferences.databaseAddress, databaseAddressValue));
        root.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any advice as to how to fix this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the return value of `FXMLLoader.load()` to a `FXMLLoader` reference.

`FXMLLoader.load()` returns the highest object in you FXML file and that is for sure not a `FXMLLoader` object.

If you want to use a controller class for event handling and proper intialization you have to set it first and load the FXML in an other way (I assume that the `SettingsWindowController` is your controller class and has a default constructor):

```
    SettingsWindowController controller = new SettingsWindowController();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(SettingsWindowController.class
            .getResource("Settings.fxml"));
    loader.setController(controller);
    AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane)loader.load();
```

Comment: I think I appreciate more what is going on now. However, if I just remove those two lines, I have nothing to call `getController()` on and I don't see how I can set a default value in the window when it starts.

Comment: I edited it, do not hesitate to ask if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks. It is starting to make sense. However, I get `javafx.fxml.LoadException: Controller value already specified.` if I switch to `loader.load()` for the AnchorPane, rather than `FXMLLoader.load(SettingsWindowController.class
                 .getResource("Settings.fxml"));` I also don't seem to get the value from my preference file into the textbox of the settings window, but that might be a problem for a separate question/more work from me to understand what is going on.

Comment: I assume you created your FXMl with SceneBuilder. Just remove the controller class within SceneBuilder.

Comment: Thanks, that is great and it is all working now. I think I also worked out the bug with setting the preference value in the text box. However, doesn't it make more sense to somehow bind the controller in scene builder and still initialise the window with values on load? Why do you have to set the controller programmatically? Is the best way/only way to do things? I am just trying to understand the theoretical reason for doing things this way.

Comment: I like to create and set it programmatically, since I am able to use a "non-default constructor". I never tried it your proposed way but I think it should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader(SettingsWindowController.class.getResource("Settings.fxml"));
AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) fxmlLoader.load();
```

Comment: `FXMLLoader.load(URL url)` does not return a `FXMLLoader`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-java.net.URL-).

Comment: You are right, i edited the answer, apologise for wrong post.